# Nextjs v13 posting to db (bad request graphql 400) and router refetch and reset

Tags: reactjs, next.js, router, react-hook-form

I am trying to figure out why I can't post data to my psql database (in a react, graphql, prisma, typescript app with nextjs (v13).
Is there a nextjs 13 command that needs to be included? The reason I suspect this is the issue is that I have used this submit handler before and I only recently changed to react v18 and next v13.

I  tried putting each option into a separate return statement with an if /else block as per below. My vscode shows no errors

My console logs return "[firstName], 1st time checking", "[firstName],3rd time checking" and "cant find data" when the page loads. When I submit the form, the same console logs are generated (#2nd time checking is never logged) and I get a bad request error in the console.

```
export default function IssueGroup() {
    const toast = useToast()
    const { me, loading: meLoading } = useMe()
    const [createIssueGroup, { loading }] = useCreateIssueGroupMutation() 
    const { data: issueGroupData, refetch } = useAllIssueGroupsQuery()

    const IssueGroupSchema = Yup.object().shape({
        title: Yup.string().required("Required"),
    })

    const form = useForm({ schema: IssueGroupSchema })
    console.log(me?.firstName , "1st time checking me")
    const onSubmit = (data: IssueGroupInput) => {
        console.log(me?.firstName, "2nd time checking me")
        if (me) 
        return form.handler(() => createIssueGroup({ variables: { data: { ...data } } })), {
            onSuccess: async () => {
                console.log("2", data)
                console.log("3", data)
                toast({ 
                    title: "Issue Group created",
                    description: "Your Issue Group has been created successfully", 
                    status: "success",
                })
                console.log("4", data)
                refetch()
                console.log("5", data)
                form.reset()
            },
            
        };
       
    }
    if (!me)
    return toast({title: "You don't have permission to create an Issue Group"})
        console.log(me?.firstName, "3rd time checking me")
        console.log("1", "cant find data")

    if (meLoading) 
        return (
            <c.Center><c.Spinner /></c.Center>
        )
```

The longer text of the error message in the console inspector (with graphql error code 400 being the only terminal response I get) as follows:

```
Error: Response not successful: Received status code 400
    at new ApolloError (index.js?a31c:29:1)
    at Object.error (QueryManager.js?d74e:141:74)
    at notifySubscription (module.js?4bb5:137:1)
    at onNotify (module.js?4bb5:176:1)
    at SubscriptionObserver.error (module.js?4bb5:229:1)
    at Object.eval [as error] (asyncMap.js?b86f:32:41)
    at notifySubscription (module.js?4bb5:137:1)
    at onNotify (module.js?4bb5:176:1)
    at SubscriptionObserver.error (module.js?4bb5:229:1)
    at eval (iteration.js?a66f:4:50)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at iterateObserversSafely (iteration.js?a66f:4:1)
    at Object.error (Concast.js?dd0c:37:43)
    at notifySubscription (module.js?4bb5:137:1)
    at onNotify (module.js?4bb5:176:1)
    at SubscriptionObserver.error (module.js?4bb5:229:1)
    at Object.error (index.js?c13a:48:1)
    at notifySubscription (module.js?4bb5:137:1)
    at onNotify (module.js?4bb5:176:1)
    at SubscriptionObserver.error (module.js?4bb5:229:1)
    at notifySubscription (module.js?4bb5:137:1)
    at onNotify (module.js?4bb5:176:1)
    at SubscriptionObserver.error (module.js?4bb5:229:1)
    at handleError (parseAndCheckHttpResponse.js?4d35:117:1)
    at eval (parseAndCheckHttpResponse.js?4d35:126:33)
```

The network tab of my chrome inspector shows the error initiator as createHttpLink. In my app, that is defined as:

```
import { ApolloClient, createHttpLink, from, fromPromise, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client"
const httpLink = createHttpLink({ uri: GRAPHQL_API_URL })
```

I can't find any other sources of information to try and understand what this error message means.

While I can see when I start my localhost, that graphql is started, I can't follow the link created in the terminal message to a page that renders a sandbox.

```
Server started at http://localhost:5555/graphql
```

This page renders text that says:

> GET query missing.

I can see the sandbox if I change that URL to: https://studio.apollographql.com/sandbox/explorer

Do I need to change my definition of GRAPHQL_API_URL and schema definition (in codegen.yml from: schema: http://localhost:5555/graphql
to this sandbox explorer definition? I think not, because I wouldn't be able to run the query successfully if that were incorrectly defined at present - the only thing I can't do at this point is the createMutation.

I added networkError to my apollo error link function and can now see an additional error log in the console, which says:

> next-dev.js?36dd:20 ServerError: Response not successful: Received
> status code 400
> at throwServerError (throwServerError.js?56ca:2:1)
> at parseJsonBody (parseAndCheckHttpResponse.js?4d35:96:25)
> at eval (parseAndCheckHttpResponse.js?4d35:132:41)

I still don't know what this means.

I have this error handler set up - I know I am catching whatever the error is in this handler.

```
try {
      const res = await mutation()
      return mutationHandler(res, actions || {}, toast, formActions)
    } catch (e) {
      // Likely an internet connection issue, or an unknown server error
      Sentry.captureException(e)
      console.log(e)
      toast({
        title: "Something went wrong, we have been notified!",
        description: "Do you have an internet connection?",
        status: "error",
      })
      return
    }
  }
```